# How to make [NsApp run] not block?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm a complete Cocoa newbie.

Right now my simple Hello World app blocks after calling `[NsApp run]` from main().

All I need is create a window and not block main().

I want my application to behave like glfw:

https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/master/src/cocoa_window.m#L1022

For some reason, it doesn't block there. In fact, you can remove this line, and it will still work.

I've been playing with a glfw source to figure out what they do differently. And for example, `[NsApp run]` blocks if I remove `[NSApp setDelegate:_glfw.ns.delegate];`

But that's not it.

According to the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication):

> The NSApplication class sets up @autorelease block during
>   initialization and inside the event loop—specifically, within its
>   initialization (or shared) and run() methods.
>
> Typically, an app creates objects either while the event loop is
>   running or by loading objects from nib files, so this lack of access
>   usually isn’t a problem. However, if you do need to use Cocoa classes
>   within the main() function itself (other than to load nib files or to
>   instantiate NSApplication), you should create an @autorelease block to
>   contain the code using the classes.

I guess that's what I need, but I have no idea how to use the @autorelease block.

**Thanks for your help.**

Comment: And you are not even going to tell why you even want to call [NsApp run] and where?

Comment: According to the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428631-run?language=objc), the app runs until you tell it to quit.

Comment: @ElTomato I've updated the question. All I need is create a window and not block main().

Comment: @Willeke it doesn't block in glfw. I'd like to figure out how they do it.

Comment: Explore the linked code, see what `GLFWApplicationDelegate` does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out.

GLFW implements its own event loop, so calling [NSApp run] is not needed:

```
NSEvent *event = [NSApp nextEventMatchingMask:NSEventMaskAny
                                        untilDate:[NSDate distantFuture]
                                           inMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                                          dequeue:YES];
    [NSApp sendEvent:event];
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking at this problem myself, and decided to organize everything everyone said and I have found into one answer.

*You should probably note that the reason `run` blocks is because it has something functionally similar to a while(1) loop inside of it which updates the window and handles events and such. Calling `[NSApp stop]` stops this loop so it wont block anymore (good), but we also have no more events (bad).*

**Overall, what GLFW does is the following:**

1. Create an NSApplication, create a delegate, and set the delegate to the application.
2. Call `run` and `stop` on the NSApp. `stop` is called inside `applicationDidFinishLaunching` of the delegate.
3. On each frame get the next event from queue and dispatch it down the application.

**More in-depth with code:** PS. All code is (altered for simplicity) from the [GLFW github](https://github.com/glfw/glfw)

```
// src/cocoa_init.m
int _glfwPlatformInit(void)
{
  ...
  //setup NSApplication, then init and set delegate
  [NSApplication sharedApplication];
  GLFWApplicationDelegate* del = [[GLFWApplicationDelegate alloc] init]; 
  [NSApp setDelegate:del];

  //This is a guard to make sure run is only called once
  if (![[NSRunningApplication currentApplication] isFinishedLaunching])
        [NSApp run];
}
```

**Note** the isFinishedLaunching guard exists because `applicationDidFinishLaunching` in the delegate only gets called after the first `run` call. If for some reason the user called `glfwInit()` again, without the guard `run` would be called, causing it to block again.

```
// src/cocoa_init.m
@interface GLFWApplicationDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
@end

@implementation GLFWApplicationDelegate

  ...

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    _glfwPlatformPostEmptyEvent();
    [NSApp stop:nil];
}
@end
```

```
// src/cocoa_window.m
void _glfwPlatformPollEvents(void)
{
    @autoreleasepool {

    for (;;)
    {
        NSEvent* event = [NSApp nextEventMatchingMask:NSEventMaskAny
                                            untilDate:[NSDate distantPast]
                                               inMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                                              dequeue:YES];
        if (event == nil)
            break;

        [NSApp sendEvent:event];
    }

    } // autoreleasepool
}
```

**Note** `glfwPollEvents` retrieves the next event from the queue, then sends the event to the application to be propogated through the responders. It functions as the main loop explained in the [documentation about event architecture](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW4).

> In the main event loop, the application object (NSApp) continuously gets the next (topmost) event in the event queue, converts it to an NSEvent object, and dispatches it toward its final destination

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same scenario.
I and found a little different solution.

Just call `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] run];` and when your window is created, call `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] stop:nil];`, the `run` call will now exit. And then you can still call the sendEvent method.