# Custom async NSApplication event loop causes random crashes

Tags: swift, macos, async-await

The following code launches a blank GUI app, but it randomly crashes when clicking off and on the window. Running it through Xcode will sometimes show `No error handler for XPC error: <private>` when it crashes, but not always.

I've made the event loop async by using `await Task.yield()`. If the await is removed, the app will not crash.

The reason for converting the loop to async is that I want to launch a GUI inside of an async function for a CLI tool. I could easily solve this by compiling a separate executable that launches the GUI in a separate process so that I don't need async, but I'd like to simplify the builds and just want to know why this is happening.

Create a `foo.swift` and run with `./foo.swift`:

```swift
#!/usr/bin/env swift
import AppKit
import Foundation

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {}

let app = NSApplication.shared
let appDelegate = AppDelegate()
NSWindow(
  contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 640, height: 400),
  styleMask: [.closable, .miniaturizable, .titled],
  backing: .buffered,
  defer: true
).makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
app.delegate = appDelegate
app.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
app.finishLaunching()
while true {
  if let ev = app.nextEvent(
    matching: .any, until: .distantFuture, inMode: .default, dequeue: true
  ) {
    app.sendEvent(ev)
  }
  await Task.yield()  // This is causing random crashes
}
```

Comment: That's not how you make an event loop in AppKit. See [`RunLoop`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/runloop). You can just enqueue your own sources/events to the _real_ runloop.

Comment: @Alexander I got this from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48023455/2687427 and GLFW repo https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/3eaf1255b29fdf5c2895856c7be7d7185ef2b241/src/cocoa_window.m#L1519 But either way, if you know why underneath it's causing random crashes when `await Task.yield()` is added, do submit it as an answer.

Comment: Yeahh.... that seems sketchy. Without knowing what else a RunLoop does (from look at its source code), how can we know if this manual re-implementation is missing anything? What you're seeing here is probably some interaction between the main thread, main runloop, and main task executor. If the task you're yeilding to is waiting on something to run on the runloop, then you'd hit a deadlock. Not sure why it would crash, though.

Comment: We'd need more detail on what exactly you're trying to achieve with the `Task.yield()` here, before anyone could suggest any particular solution

Comment: Yeah, I agree; I really wish we had the full implementation of `NSApplication.run`, then people can override it a bit easier. Tbh, I'm not really looking for a solution here, and it's just more of a theoretical question. I have a solution, just want to know why. Nevertheless, I discovered this while trying to programmatically create a GUI within the `AsyncArgumentParser.run` method. I was playing with making `VZVirtualMachine.start` async, then made an async function that starts the GUI and the VM. The VM never started, because I realised the while loop blocks it.

Comment: Adding the `Task.yield` is just a classic method that I know of to make a forever loop async by adding a suspension point to allow other async functions to run. The VM actually runs and GUI updates, but then I realise it crashes easily. This led to the above tiny example code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255942/discussion-between-alexander-and-nelson-yeung).